# How to hash a password using SHA1 as its being entered into a database through a form field

Tags: php, mysql, sql

im trying to figure out how to store a password in a database using encryption SHA1 and am struggling to figure it out.

I know how to enter it in unencrypted through a form, but not how to have it be automatically encrypted for when viewing the entered tables in phpmyadmin.

I know that if I want to encrypt a specific password, I can enter it directly through SQL like this:

INSERT INTO registrations(password) values(SHA1('encrypted password'));

but im not sure how to have it automatically do this for when I enter a password in through a field.

Also, please understand that I have only been doing PHP for a couple of months now so am still relatively new.

Heres what ive got so far;

```
$stmt= $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO registrations (customerID, email, username, password, m firstName, lastName) values (:customerID, :email, :username, :password, :firstName, :lastName)");
```

What im trying to do is hash the password only, not the rest of variables. its probably something very simple but I cant figure out how to do it!

Comment: Dont use `SHA1`, use `password_hash`, please. Why not do `$hash = sha1($password)`?...

Comment: ive tried: $stmt= $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO registrations (customerID, email, username, password, firstName, lastName) values (SHA1(:customerID, :email, :username, :password, :firstName, :lastName))"); and many other variations with no success. Im trying to go by some notes I have but am struggling to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily use

```
    $stmt= $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO registrations (customerID, email, username, password, m firstName, lastName) values (:customerID, :email, :username, SHA1(:password), :firstName, :lastName)");
```

However, for security reasons you should consider using http://php.net/manual/de/function.password-hash.php (available in PHP>=5.5) or special frameworks https://defuse.ca/php-pbkdf2.htm

Comment: Thank you, im not sure how I missed that. Im still wrapping my head around PHP. Ill have a look at password_hash now thanks, as the notes ive been given are a bit old im guessing as they are using SHA1 in them.

Comment: It's not just about using a hash, also using salt (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_%28cryptography%29) strenghtens security against brute force attacks

Comment: There's an library called [password_compat](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat) for lower versions of PHP.

Comment: +1 to mention salting. Read [You're Probably Storing Passwords Incorrectly](http://blog.codinghorror.com/youre-probably-storing-passwords-incorrectly/)